# How to create this grainy text overlay effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, text, photoshop-effects

There is a cool text overlay effect I saw [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0ouXAjYlYg).
[image]
How can I make an effect such as this in Adobe Photoshop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this fits the bill for what you were looking for (or close):

1. Blending Mode - Overlay
2. Menu -> Filter -> Noise -> Add Noise (Distribution: Normal, Monochrome Checked)

[image]